# Android find all hardcoded strings in code using Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to find all hard-coded strings in my code to move them into `strings.xml` file **for future localization**. Such as :

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Hardcoded text",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I using Android Studio.

Comment: doesn't android Lint help you out here? I would try lintRelease.

Comment: I guess you can find `"strings"` with REGEX search like `"(.)+"`, then just make a `strings.xml` for whatever you need from that.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Go to `Analyze` > `Run Inspection By Name...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

and type:

- `Hardcoded Text` to find the hardcoded strings in
  the **.xml files**;
- `Hardcoded Strings` to find the hardcoded strings in the **.java files**.

Run it against the **whole project**, and you should get an inspection results panel that will show the hardcoded text instances.

Comment: that's the full answer

Comment: please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56121083/3904109 it may help you...

Comment: But, i got library strings  also how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 16):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043809/how-can-i-find-all-hard-coded-strings-in-my-project-in-android-studio) answer hasn't getting to me any result.

Nonetheless, for future searches :

In Android Studio 1.2.2 added new Option `Hardcoded strings`(not a `Hardcoded text`) and this getting to me perfect searches result.

Answer (score 3):

After android studio 1.2.2 It seems pretty easy way to do it,

Go to Analyze

Run Inspection by name

Type : **HardCoded Text**

And then by selecting appropriate module's option you can get all hard coded Strings in your whole project.

Tip : Short key : `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `I`

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043809/how-can-i-find-all-hard-coded-strings-in-my-project-in-android-studio), isn't it relevant for your problem ? 
Edit : just don't forget to check "File mask(s)" box in the window after having typed "Hardcoded text", and select `*.java`, if you want to search in Java files.

And after you found all your hardcoded strings, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977208/auto-generate-string-reference-in-android-studio) may help you to transfer them to XML.

Comment: no, is not. This method gives to me all hardcoded strings in `*.xml` files (layout, themes,etc.) not in java code.

Comment: Check "File mask(s)" box in the window after having typed "Hardcoded text", and select `*.java`