# Find all hardcoded dimens in code using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-lint

How to find all hardcoded dimensions both in xml layout files and in code in Android Studio? I want to move them over to dimens.xml.

Basically, I want something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39130143, but for dimensions instead of strings.

Answer (score 4):

This should work -

Press `Ctrl + Shift + F` or  `Cmd + Shift + F` (in mac) to search in project.

Go to Options and choose Regular Expression.

Now search `"((\d)+)dp"` in search bar which should give you all the hardcoded dimensions.

If you have dimensions as decimal values you can change the regex pattern accordingly. This one worked in my case. 
Also, if you want to search in specific area, you can do that too with this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can search all the hard coded dimension in Android studio using **Find in path**.

Go to

> Edit > Find > Find in path

In option tab ->

- General -> select Regular expression
- Scope -> You can select the sope of the search
- File name filter - > you can select FileMasks as **`*.xml`**

And you can start the search now, add **`\ddp`** or **`[0-9]dp`** in Text to find.

Done you can see all the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create the custom lint for that, since currently it can check for `0dp` in code and use of pixel instead of dimension.