# Extract all hardcoded strings to string resource

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> combination to extract single String to string resource. But I am wondering is there anything that I can extract all string of my project into string resource?

Also Android studio not making same String to string resource if I make one of them.

```
String s = "Hello World";
String s2 = "Hello World";
```

For example. I make "Hello World" to string resource still another remain Hardcoded in same file as well in the project too.

```
String s = getString(R.string.helloworld);
String s2 = "Hello World";
```

If anyone know something like that.

Comment: Just use Find and Replace. It will be more efficient !

Comment: There is no need to close this one, as it neither fall in any of these,       `duplicate of, off-topic because,unclear what you're asking, too broad,  primarily opinion-based`. This is just a question to know if there is any option/tool/feature available or not.

Comment: you have to spend a little time for that. As I know there is no such options except opening each file and replacing the same String..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna try to find some better option. This type of option available in xcode so I think something like that in android studio too.

Comment: Ok I will but [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/find-and-replace-in-path.html) may help you little bit on the secondary option which was finding and replacing.

Answer (score 27):

As your requirements and as I know there is no such feature in android studio you were really searching for, But here are some alternative ways that can help you.

- Go to "`Analyze` > `Run Inspection ..`", and type `"Hardcoded strings"`. Run that in your whole project, and you will get an inspection results panel that will show all the hardcoded text of projects. Then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you'll get an option to automatically extract that Strings.
- Another approach is to **Find and Replace** But It's not better because of time consumption. To simplify the approach you can have a look at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/find-and-replace-in-path.html) for flexibility.

Comment: yes that help me better. but it not finding in the xml.

Comment: @CreativeAndroid Analyze - Run inspection by name - "Hardcoded text   Android Lint" and choose file mask *.xml

Comment: @CreativeAndroid Yah thats so. `hardcoded texts` will show all hardcoded strings of xml and `hardcoded strings` of internationalization issues will show strings of java files.

Comment: It only works for me in the layout file, not in my java classes

Comment: This is not working in with latest version (2.3.3). That option has been removed. So bad! Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: @AmeerHamza, brother, that is working only in some places like @ Avi Parshan mentioned. Not all places like before.

Answer (score 4):

For hardcoded strings in XML layout files:

Click on Analyze -> Run inspection by name -> enter Hardcoded strings -> select the whole project -> OK.
Here, you will get all the hardcoded strings from your xml layout files only that u can extract to strings.xml by:

Click on the hardcoded text -> Alt + Enter -> extract from resource -> enter your corresponding resource name for that string -> OK

For hardcoded strings in Java class code:

Click on Analyze -> Run inspection by name -> enter Hardcoded texts -> select the whole project -> OK.
Here, you will get all the hardcoded strings from your Java class files only that u can extract to strings.xml by:

Click on the hardcoded text -> Alt + Enter -> extract from resource -> enter your corresponding resource name for that string -> OK -> add getString for each string resource created in your java code.

Hence, Hardcoded strings -> Java class code whereas
Hardcoded texts -> Xml layout files in Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

In Android 3.2.1 you can go to `Edit->Find->Find In Path...` and then search for `android:text="` .  This will give you a list of all the hardcoded strings in `xml files`.

Search for `Toast.makeText` to find all the toast items from the `java files`.

Search for `setText("` to search for text sets in `java files` and so forth.

You can do searches like this for items you would like to find throughout the project and replace.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following script to extract all hardcoded strings from an `activity.xml` file and add them to `strings.xml`. (Bash/Linux):

**Usage:** `extractAll.sh activity_main.xml strings.xml`
Original files are backed up before changes are made.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
#  Extract All Hardcoded Strings From an Activity XML File and Save New 
#  Versions of the activity.xml and strings.xml
################################################################################

#check the number of arguments supplied, print usage if not 2
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "extract all hardcoded strings from activity.xml and update .xml files"
    echo "original files are saved with .bak extension"
    echo "usage: $0 activity.xml strings.xml"
    exit
fi

#backup input files
#TODO: save these backups in another folder so they don't cause build error
cp $1 $1.bak
cp $2 $2.bak

#grep for hardcoded strings, for each one sed out special characters, change 
#all to lower case, replace space characters with underscores, truncate string
#variable names to 30 characters. The result will be the name of the new string
#variable entered in strings.xml
grep -Po "(?<=android:text=\")[^\"]+(?=\")" $1 | while read -r HARDSTRING ; do
    STRINGVARNAME=`echo $HARDSTRING | sed 's/\([\d0-\d31]\|[\d33-\d35]\|\$\|[\d37-\d47]\|[\d58-\d64]\|[\d91-\d96]\|[\d123-\d126]\)//g'|sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'|sed 's/ /_/g'|head -c 30`
    #substitute each hardcoded string with the string variable name
    sed -i "s/$HARDSTRING/@string\/$STRINGVARNAME/" $1
    #get the number of lines in strings.xml file
    NUMLINES=`wc -l < $2`
    #insert string definition at second-to-last line of strings.xml
    let "NUMLINES++" #I had to increment mine to get the desired result
    #add an entry to the strings.xml defining the newly extracted string
    sed -i "$NUMLINES""i\\    <string name=\""$STRINGVARNAME"\">$HARDSTRING</string>\\" $2
done
```

Final note: `wc -l` returned one less than expected in my test case using a `strings.xml` file created by Android Studio (I suspect because the last line had no newline). This caused `sed -i` to insert the new line at the third-to-last position instead of the desired second-to-last. My fix was to increment the result of `wc -l` using `let`.

**References:**
[What are invalid characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/what-are-invalid-characters-in-xml)
[sed one-liner to convert all uppercase to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569825/sed-one-liner-to-convert-all-uppercase-to-lowercase)
[How to process each output line in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317961/how-to-process-each-output-line-in-a-loop)
[How can I truncate a line of text longer than a given length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430979/how-can-i-truncate-a-line-of-text-longer-than-a-given-length)
[Linux Shell Script - String Comparison with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891491/linux-shell-script-string-comparison-with-wildcards)
[How to insert a string into second to last line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483844/how-to-insert-a-string-into-second-to-last-line-of-a-file)
[Check number of arguments passed to a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E82085_01/150/funtional_artifacts_guide/or-fasg-standards.htm
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22828

Answer (score 0):

I believe the shortcut you are looking for is (on a Mac) <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: This one is for creating a constant, not strings.xml extraction

Comment: It's Option + Enter on Mac