# How to insert a string into second to last line of a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an question about how to insert a string into the second to last line of a file.

### For example:

```
$ cat diff_a.txt
students
teacher
mike
john

$ cat diff_b.txt
python
bash shell
Java
```

### Expected Result should be:

```
$ cat diff_b.txt
python
bash shell
mike
Java
```

### If I use the following command, it will append string "mike" into the last line of diff_b.txt

```
$ grep mike diff_a.txt >> diff_b.txt
$ cat diff_b.txt
python
bash shell
Java
mike
```

### Question:

```
How should I put "mike" into second to last line of diff_b.txt ?
```

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the string `'mike'` into diff_b.txt or how to insert whatever string is at the 2nd-last line of diff_a.txt into diff_b.txt? The rest of your question sounds like you want the former but then if so why are you showing us diff_a.txt at all? Why are you doing `grep mike diff_a.txt` to get `mike` instead of just `echo mike`? Whatever it is you need please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sed` to insert a line before a specific line, given it's position :

```
sed '4i\My New Line\' my_file.txt
```

Will insert "My New Line" on the fourth line

You can use `wc -l` to get the number of line in the file :

```
$ wc -l < my_file.txt
5
```

### Complete example to directly answer your question :

```
$ cat my_file.txt
Hello
World
There is another line

$ sed -i "`wc -l < my_file.txt`i\\My New Line\\" my_file.txt

$ cat my_file.txt
Hello
World
My New Line
There is another line
```

- Adding `-i` so sed actually edit the file
- Using double quotes, otherwise substitution and expansion is not performed within single quotes.
- Escaping `\`

Comment: Just brilliant, this is the command I get. `sed "`cat diff_b.txt | wc -l`i\\`grep mike diff_a.txt`\\" diff_b.txt`

Comment: Perhaps `sed '$iMy New Line' file` would do?

Comment: gsed for mac users.

Answer (score 2):

To read the output from any command, such as `grep mike diff_a.txt`, into the second-to-last line of diff_b.txt:

```
ed -s diff_b.txt <<< $'$-1r !grep mike diff_a.txt\nwq'
```

This puts `ed` into script mode, then feeds commands to it as if they were typed as input:

- `$' ... '` - a quoted string of:
- `$-1r` - on the `$` last line minus 1, `r` read from:
- `! grep ...` - the shell command grep ...
- `\n` - end the `r` command with a carriage return
- `wq` - `w`rite (save the file) and `q`uit ed

This is much simpler for your example, if you already know what text you want to insert:

```
ed -s diff_b.txt <<< $'$-1a\nmike\n.\nwq'
```

Here we use the `a` append command (ended by a carriage return), enter the `mike` text (ended by a carriage return), then exit `a` append mode with a `.` (ended by a carriage return), then save and exit.

Answer (score 1):

I have a python solution. Read the lines from the file into a list using `readlines` and then inserting a value.

```
import re
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
fp = open(file_name)
lines = fp.readlines()
your_output = lines.insert(len(lines)-1,"insert text") # you can also use sys.argv[2] if you want two inputs, first is file_name (also accepts file path), second can be your insert text
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hacky solution, but you can use negative line counts with `head` to get all but the last line, insert your new line, then use `tail` to grab just the last line of the original file.  You'll have to redirect the output to a temporary file first, then overwrite your original file.

```
 ( head -n -1 diff_b.txt
 echo "mike"
 tail -n 1 diff_b.txt ) > tmp.txt
 mv tmp.txt diff_b.txt
```

Comment:  for using `head`

Answer (score 1):

> grep a line from a file and insert to the second to last position into another file

if you don't have a special chars...

```
$ tac file2 | sed "2i$(grep mike file1)" | tac

python
bash shell
mike
Java
```

Answer (score 0):

Create test file

```
echo -e 'Hi\n123\nBye' > test.txt
```

[image]