# how to scan a springboot application to list hard coded values?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, environment-variables, externalizable

We are looking at externalizing the configuration of an springboot app. Is there a way to scan the code and list all the hard coded values?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569783/extract-all-hardcoded-strings-to-string-resource you need to use some IDE like IntelliJ for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some IDE like IntelliJ for example. Open the Project and go to "**Analyze**" option and then select "**Run Inspection By Name**" and after that choose option "hard coded strings". [image]