# How can I truncate a line of text longer than a given length?

Tags: string, bash, shell, string-length, truncation

How would you go about removing everything after *x* number of characters? For example, cut everything after 15 characters and add `...` to it.

`This is an example sentence` should turn into `This is an exam...`

Answer (score 29):

GnuTools `head` can use chars rather than lines:

```sh
head -c 15 <<<'This is an example sentence'
```

Although consider that `head -c` only deals with bytes, so this is incompatible with multi-bytes characters like UTF-8 umlaut `ü`.

Bash built-in string indexing works:

```sh
str='This is an example sentence'
echo "${str:0:15}"
```

Output:

```
This is an exam
```

And finally something that works with ksh, dash, zsh…:

```sh
printf '%.15s\n' 'This is an example sentence'
```

Even programmatically:

```sh
n=15
printf '%.*s\n' $n 'This is an example sentence'
```

If you are using Bash, you can directly assign the output of `printf` to a variable and save a sub-shell call with:

```sh
trim_length=15
full_string='This is an example sentence'
printf -v trimmed_string '%.*s' $trim_length "$full_string"
```

Comment: `cut` is also an option I guess, it handles multibyte characters as well

Comment: `${str:0:15}` is very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use `sed`:

```
echo 'some long string value' | sed 's/\(.\{15\}\).*/\1.../'
```

Output:

```
some long strin...
```

---

This solution has the advantage that short strings do not get the `...` tail added:

```
echo 'short string' | sed 's/\(.\{15\}\).*/\1.../'
```

Output:

```
short string
```

So it's one solution for all sized outputs.

Answer (score 10):

Use `cut`:

```
echo "This is an example sentence" | cut -c1-15
This is an exam
```

This includes characters (to handle multi-byte chars) 1-15, c.f. `cut(1)`

```
     -b, --bytes=LIST
            select only these bytes

     -c, --characters=LIST
            select only these characters
```

Comment: Doesn't work well with strings containing newlines

Answer (score 4):

Awk can also accomplish this:

```
$ echo 'some long string value' | awk '{print substr($0, 1, 15) "..."}'
some long strin...
```

In awk, `$0` is the current line.  `substr($0, 1, 15)` extracts characters 1 through 15 from `$0`.   The trailing `"..."` appends three dots.

Answer (score 3):

[Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/todd-a-jacobs) actually has a good answer however I chose to change it up a little to make the function better and remove unnecessary parts :p

```
trim() {
    if (( "${#1}" > "$2" )); then
      echo "${1:0:$2}$3"
    else
      echo "$1"
    fi
}
```

In this version the appended text on longer string are chosen by the third argument, the max length is chosen by the second argument and the text itself is chosen by the first argument.

No need for variables :)

Comment: This is compatible with ksh, zsh, dash, and a lot more shells, as it is not a Bashism implementation: `trim(){ printf '%.*s' $2 "$1";}`. And if you want it Bash only but faster; you can do: `printf -v trimmed_string '%.*s' $trim "$full_string"`

Comment: You need examples of how to call it:  `trim "My Long String" <maxLen> "..."`

Answer (score 2):

### Using Bash Shell Expansions (No External Commands)

If you don't care about shell portability, you can do this entirely within Bash using a number of different [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html). This avoids shelling out to external commands. For example:

```
trim () {
    local str ellipsis_utf8
    local -i maxlen

    # use explaining variables; avoid magic numbers        
    str="$*"
    maxlen="15"
    ellipsis_utf8=$'\u2026'

    # only truncate $str when longer than $maxlen
    if (( "${#str}" > "$maxlen" )); then
      printf "%s%s\n" "${str:0:$maxlen}" "${ellipsis_utf8}"
    else
      printf "%s\n" "$str"
    fi
}

trim "This is an example sentence." # This is an exam…
trim "Short sentence."              # Short sentence.

trim "-n Flag-like strings."        # Flag-like strin…
trim "With interstitial -E flag."   # With interstiti…
```

You can also loop through an entire file this way. Given a file containing the same sentences above (one per line), you can use the [**read** builtin's default *REPLY* variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-REPLY) as follows:

```
while read; do
    trim "$REPLY"
done < example.txt
```

Whether or not this approach is faster or easier to read is debatable, but it's 100% Bash and executes without forks or subshells.

Comment: After some discussion on the GNU mailing list, it turns out that Bash's option parsing for the echo builtin has some known POSIX-imposed limitations. Specifically, it doesn't handle the end-of-options flag as most other builtins do. Using the printf builtin is therefore the better option if the concatenated arguments to trim() could *start* with `-n`, `-e`, or `-E`.