# Converting hard coded strings to string resources

Tags: android, android-studio

So, i kind of created a monster. Built an android game for few years and used lots of hardcoded strings. Now i want to support different languages. My questions - is there an automatic way to create these resources?

for example tell Android studio for all the "hard coded" warnings apply extract string resource.

I aw aware of the inspect code that show you localization warnings, i am looking for a way to automate the fix

Comment: May this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569783/extract-all-hardcoded-strings-to-string-resource

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible to fix that automatically. You need to press `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i` and type `hardcoded strings`. After completion of the finding process, manually create them in `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a link to site that will convert your string.xml to different language you want and then download translated string.xml in your stings folder, it will translate each string step by step, if this is what you want, hope it helps

https://asrt.gluege.boerde.de